# Relation between $\frac{1}{|x|}$ and dimension of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We know the following: $|\ln(|x|)|=\frac{1}{|x|}$ and $|\nabla \arctan(\frac x y)|=\frac{1}{|z|}$  (for z=(x,y)).

Can we find in general (for arbitrary $n$) a function, which has the property that the Euclidean norm of the gradient is $\frac{1}{|z|}$? If not, for which dimensions can we find such a function? What about other norms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z \rightarrow ln( |z| )$ has that property regardless of the dimension of $z$.

Indeed, at every point $z \neq 0$, the radial component of the gradient is zero (because the function has a spherical symmetry), and the axial component of the gradient is equal to $\frac{d(ln|z|)}{d|z|} = \frac{1}{|z|}$.